# How do I make a regex match a query string?

Tags: regex, web, query-string

I'm working on a simple router, and I need to be able to identify if there's a query-like structure at the end of a URL address.
What I came up with:

```
(\?([^&=]+)=([^&=]+)&?)+$
```

simply does not work! It works on a first iteration: i.e. `xxx?foo=bar`, but definitely not on two i.e. `xxx?foo=bar&greeting=hello` won't work.

What am I doing wrong? And also: Is there a better solution to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you use a simpler [`[&?]([^&=]+)=([^&=]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/Wz3fZW/1)  to get multiple matches?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh, yeah! I did not think of that possibility. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Shall I post for you to accept my answer or is Dima's one below fine?

Comment: Both are fine, yours is more elegant imo. || wait, actually: what about xxx&foo=bar? it should work as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "work"? `foo` and `bar` are captured.

Comment: Thing is: there has got to be a question mark (?) at the begin of the query.

Comment: Try [`(?:^\?|&)([^&=]+)=([^&=]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/Wz3fZW/4) or [`(?:^\?|(?!^)&)([^&=]+)=([^&=]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/Wz3fZW/5).

Answer (score 0):

You need to match one key-value pair (`([^&=]+)=([^&=]+)`) preceded with a question mark (`\?([^&=]+)=([^&=]+)`) followed by zero to any number of key-value pairs preceded by an ampersand each (`(?:&([^&=]+)=([^&=]+))*`):

```
\?([^&=]+)=([^&=]+)(?:&([^&=]+)=([^&=]+))*$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/OHdRHS/1

Comment: Thank you! but what I don't get is: Why is there a need to repeat this key-pair logic a second time, rather than wrap everything in a +plus?

Comment: @JoeTheMan: to ensure the first occurrence is preceded exactly with `?` and the following occurrences are preceded exactly with `&`. The easiest way to achieve this with regex is repeat the pair expression (i.e. `\?(<pair>)(?:&<pair>)*`), I believe.